# Kernel of selfadjoint compact operator is trivial

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be separable Hilbert space and $K(H)$ the space of all compact operators acting in $H$. If $x\in K(H)$ and $x=x^*$ then is it true that $\ker(x)\neq \{0\}$?. Where $\ker(x)$ is the kernel of $x$. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.   An example of a self-adjoint compact with a trivial kernel is as follows: define $x:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ by
$$
x\left[(\xi_k)_{k = 1}^\infty\right]
 = (\xi_k/k)_{k=1}^\infty 
$$